# VS2010 C++ F7 doesn't create executable in 'debug'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, path, exe

I'm beginner at programming and I've got this problem with debugging. My programme builds successfully but after I debug it, I just get this error:

"unable to start program 'projects\workspls\Debug\workpls.exe'.
System cannot find this file"

I already read a lot about it and I believe I'm supposed to change certain paths in Solutions Properties to match since there is no executable created in 'debug' or any other place after building program. But every time I go to Solutions Properties I get confused and don't have a clue what to change. 
Would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: The bigger problem is that keyboard shortcuts vary depending on your configuration settings. Try using the menus instead, it's much easier when you're first starting out. You can learn the keyboard shortcuts later.

Comment: Thanks for respond. Unfortunately, that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you saying that after a build `workpls.exe` doesn't exist anywhere on your system (whether or not it's in the expected place)?  Can you post the `<project name>.log` logfile, or at least relevant snippets if it's too long?

Comment: Yes. Build started 31/01/2012 20:16:28.
     1>Project "C:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\workpls\workpls.vcxproj" on node 2 (build target(s)).
     1>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "Debug\workpls.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "Debug\workpls.unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "Debug\workpls.lastbuildstate".
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\workpls\workpls.vcxproj" (build target(s)).

Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07

Comment: Have you tried googling for ".unsuccessfulbuild" or "AlwaysCreate"? They stood out to me and there are some interesting search results. Not sure if they'll help you though.

Comment: @twsaef: Those two things are normal. They appear in the build log with the default settings. No cause for concern there.

Comment: The problem is that nothing is being compiled. At minimum, it should have a heading `ClCompile:` and it should list all of your source files that are compiled. Ensure that you actually have added the source files to your project and that they have the appropriate extension. Then right-click on your source files in the Solution Explorer, click "Properties", and ensure that the "Excluded From Build" property is set to "No" and that the "Item Type" property is set to "C/C++ compiler".

Answer (score 0):

if your output said "Finished generating code", then look at the file path where visual studio wrote the exe.

My exe files were being written relative to the solution, not to the various projects where I was writing the code (as I had expected).

But until I read the previous answers, I didn't think to look anywhere except under the project in the debug directory - the usual place for visual studio.